# What is the purpose of a pipe after stdout redirect?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I was reading the documentation for [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#using-standard-input) and saw a shell redirect-then-pipe construct that I haven't seen before:

```
echo -e 'FROM alpine \nRUN echo "created from standard input"' > Dockerfile | tar -cf - Dockerfile
```

The output of `echo` is redirected to `Dockerfile` and then there is the `|` to `tar` which as far as I can see will always be nothing. In situations like this I've always combined commands with `&&` or `||` so I was wondering if there is a special purpose to using a pipe-of-nothing in this case?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: `tar -cf -` tries to write an archive to the terminal. It throws "tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)" in GNU/tar: others might be less cautious.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the command given in the question is just part of a longer pipeline: `echo -e 'FROM alpine \nRUN echo "created from standard input"' > Dockerfile | tar -cf - Dockerfile | gzip -9 | docker run ...` (follow the “Kaniko” link).

Comment: @StephenKitt  That fixes the tar options -- thanks. That reduces it to a plain race condition: does the tar read Dockerfile (or fail *not found*, or read an earlier version, or get an empty file because the redirect created it already) before the echo writes it? I would not expect this to be deterministic, given that shells presumably sets up pipework end-to-front to avoid SigPipe failures.

Answer (score 0):

The command-line is valid, and it's not a typo.

You can observe that it works if you run the command inside a docker container:

```
docker run -it --rm alpine sh -c 'echo -e "FROM alpine \nRUN echo \"created from standard input\"" > Dockerfile | tar -cf - Dockerfile'
```

The same behaviour can be observed with the `cat` command:

```
echo -e 'FROM alpine \nRUN echo "created from standard input"' > Dockerfile | cat Dockerfile
```

My guess is that you probably misunderstood the options given to `tar`. It is not reading from stdin, but rather it is writing to stdout.

#### Explanaton

The shell creates the first process (`echo`), along with its stdout (`Dockerfile`), then the next process is created (`tar`). Both processes start running, and since `Dockerfile` already exists, `tar` it is able to start reading it, and writes the output to stdout.

In some cases, stdout is a tty (as some of the comments have observed), so you must then replace stdout with something that tar can write to, such as a file (`Dockerfile.tar`). Without changing the original command, simply add output redirection to the tar command to write to a file instead, and you will be able to observe the same results.

```
echo -e 'FROM alpine \nRUN echo "created from standard input"' >Dockerfile | tar -cf - Dockerfile >Dockerfile.tar
```

Comment: It's syntactically valid but not safe. It put the desired data in the tar sometimes, primarily because echo is builtin, but not always. Try `env echo ... >x | tar cf tarfile x` or `/bin/echo ... > x | tar cf tarfile x` and I'll bet at least most of the time it doesn't work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't think it has anything to do with being builtin. If I replace `echo` in the first example with `/bin/echo` from coreutils, I also observe the same behaviour. The second example always worked for me. The first one you gave doesn't always work for reasons I suspect have to do with the echo command having to start later than the first two, but even `base64 </dev/random | head -c 1G > x | tar cf x.tar x` always worked for me, so the size of the file does not seem to have any negative effects